# Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I checked the [packages list](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php?package_type=package&distro=kinetic) for kinetic and it does have geographic_msgs listed so it should not be giving this error

I installed ROS on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS following the [steps here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu).
The command I used :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs
```

I'm running ROS 1.12.6, also I've been using my Velodyne VLP-16 to bag the data and display the data in rviz but I'm having problems getting this package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257274/unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs/) by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-18**:
How did you install ROS? Which OS is this? What platform / architecture? Please copy-paste the exact commands you used that resulted in the output you posted.

**Comment by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on 2017-03-18**:
I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reinstalled ROS and it works now, thanks.

---

Originally posted by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) with karma: 45 on 2017-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use this line to install the required message type.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [ssohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29828/ssohin/) with karma: 56 on 2018-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-28**:
This is what OP said isn't working.

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2018-11-03**:
It's working now